# PHP if previous page was certain page on my site then show alert box with message

Tags: javascript, php

How could I use PHP or Javascript to check if a user's previous page was a certain page on my site and then if so, show an alert box?

Comment: sessions would be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be circumvented if a person really wanted to.

```
//on the page for the alert
session_start();
if($_SESSION['lastPage']=='??'){
echo 'alert';
}

//on the page you want to detect if the user came from
session_start();
$_SESSION['lastPage']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)